# How can I change the attribute of a class from another class

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I'm making a FIFO queue and am trying to change the values of job_ID and job_type in the Node class from the Queue class but when I run my code, I do not get any errors, but the value of job_ID and job_type do not change after. How can I fix this?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.job_ID = self.data[1]
        self.job_priority = self.data[2]
        self.job_type = self.data[3]
        self.next_node = next_node
        self.time_added = time()
        self.time_stamp = ctime(self.time_added)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self,new_node):
        self.next_node = new_node

class Queue:
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def enqueue(self, data):
        data = data.split()
        new_item = Node(data)
        print("Adding job " + new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + new_item.time_stamp + ".")
        print("The prority of the job is: " + new_item.job_priority)
        print("The job type is: " + new_item.job_type)
        current = self.head
        if current is None:
            self.head = new_item
        else:
            while current.get_next():
                current = current.get_next()
            current.set_next(new_item)

    def dequeue(self):
        current = self.head
        if current != None:
            print("Completed job " + current.job_ID + " in " + str(int(time() - current.time_added)) + " seconds.")
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            print("No current tasks - time for a coffee break!")

    def modify(self, x):
        current = self.head
        x = x.split()
        while current != None:
            if x[1] in current.get_data():
                current.job_priority = x[2]
                current.job_type = x[3]
            else:
                print('meow')
            current = current.get_next()
```

The `modify(self, x)` function is supposed to change the values of job_ID and job_type for a given node but it is not working and is still returning the original values of the two attributes.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed. I don't see where you use `modify()`

Comment: The values are correct when I look at them using print, but I think the problem is that when I say current.job_priority = x[2], the value of current.job_priority is not changing

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it and test it. I don't see where you run `modify`. Maybe you use copy of Node and it changes in different node. Or you have two nodes in the same values and you change in one node and check in another.

Comment: I see some problem - you have `job_priority` in two places - `self.data` and  `current.job_priority`. If you change `current.job_priority` then you still have old value in `self.data`. If you now check `get_data()` then you see old value. But if you check `job_priority` then you see new value. You have to change `current.data` when you change `current.job_priority`. Or `get_data()` should return `[self.data[0], self.job_ID, self,job_priorit, self.job_type]`

Comment: or maybe you should keep only `data[0]` in `self.data` ? `self.data = data[0]` ?